# Linear Regression with Gradient Descent from Scratch

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the linear regression with gradient descent algorithm from scratch. I've appropriated the code from a youtube video and want to test it out on a csv dataset.

I am getting the following error when trying to display the regression line:
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
self.weights = self.weights - self.lr * dw"

Here is the code:

```
class LinReg():

    def __init__(self, lr=0.01, n_iters=1000):
        self.lr = lr
        self.n_iters = n_iters
        self.weights = None
        self.bias = None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        self.weights = np.zeros(n_features)
        self.bias = 0

        for _ in range(self.n_iters):

            y_pred = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias

            dw = (1/n_samples) * np.dot(X.T, (y_pred - y))
            db = (1/n_samples) * np.sum(y_pred - y)

            self.weights = self.weights - self.lr * dw
            self.bias = self.bias - self.lr * db

    def predict(self, X):
        y_pred = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias
        return y_pred

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('prices.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,2].values.reshape(-1,1) # assuming the first column is the feature
y = df.iloc[:,3].values # assuming the second column is the target


# X, y = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=20, random_state=4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.show()

reg = LinReg()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = reg.predict(X_test)

def MSE(y_test, predictions):
    return np.mean(y_test - predictions)**2

MSE = MSE(y_test, predictions)
print(MSE)

y_pred_line = reg.predict(X)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
m1 = plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color=cmap(0.9), s=10)
m2 = plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color=cmap(0.5), s=10)
plt.plot(X, y_pred_line, color='black', linewidth=2, label="predictions")
plt.show()
print(y_pred_line)
```

I was having some issues with the syntax but now that that is resolved, this is (hopefully) all that's left to fix. I've included all the code in its entirety for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

The error "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract `self.weights = self.weights - self.lr * dw` " is occurring because there are `NaN` or `Inf` values in the arrays `dw` or `db`.

You can try checking if the `dw` or `db`arrays have `NaN` or `Inf` values using `NumPy's` `'isnan'` or `'isinf'` functions. If there are such values, you need to replace them with a suitable value, for example the mean of the other values in the array, or 0.

Example like

```py
import numpy as np

dw = (1/n_samples) * np.dot(X.T, (y_pred - y))

if np.isnan(dw).any() or np.isinf(dw).any():
    dw = np.where(np.isnan(dw), 0, dw)
    dw = np.where(np.isinf(dw), 0, dw)

db = (1/n_samples) * np.sum(y_pred - y)

if np.isnan(db) or np.isinf(db):
    db = 0
```